# Why is everything a Functor and what about Monomorphic types

Tags: haskell

I'm building an optimizer for various function calls in haskell, here's my AST

```
 data Expr = ExprCall { _fname :: Text, _fparams :: [Expr] }
              | ExprVar { _var :: Text }
              | ExprNat { _nat :: Int }
```

And here is an example of syntax, `mod` and `random` are external functions and their semantics are opaque to haskell.

```
mod(random(), 10)
```

All it has is the AST representation of the syntax, for the example above that would be:

```
ExprCall "mod" [ExprCall "random" [], ExprNat 10]
```

I have a lot of passes that have type `Expr->Expr` and I have a function called `descend` which traverses the AST and applies a pass to every `Expr`. Here is my descend function

```
{- # LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
descend :: (Expr -> Expr) -> Expr -> Expr
descend f ExprCall   { .. } = ExprCall _fname $ map f _fparams
-- Base expressions
descend f other = f other
```

Now I realize this is exacatly what `Data.Traversable` does and I wanted to make my Expr an instance of that, however, all typeclasses in that hierarchy `Functor`, `Foldable`, `Traversable` etc only accept kinds `* -> *`. Why?

Is there some way I can make my `Expr` to a `(* -> *)` so that it makes sense logically? Alternatively, is there a way to have monomorphic traversables?

What are the advantages of declaring data as `data Expr a` compared to what I have, `data Expr`?

Comment: Are you sure you want `f other` instead of `other`? Are you sure you want `map f _fparams` instead of `map (descend f) _fparams`? Are you sure you want `ExprCall _fname $ map f _fparams` instead of `f (ExprCall _fname (map (descend f) _fparams))`? There's a lot of variants that all seem sensible, and the type gives you (and your users) no guidance about which one this should be. `fmap`'s type, though, does give guidance: all and only the "contained values" in its second argument are modified, and the structure is left untouched, and this property is partially checked by the type system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymorphism for these classes has some benefits: the types are more descriptive, and they prevent certain implementation mistakes.

The main reason for both of these advantages is that there are generally much fewer implementations of polymorphic types than more specialized ones. If we exclude exceptions and infinite loops, there are really only two ways to implement `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`, and one is a constant function, so only the other is really sensible:

```
fmap f (Just a) = Just (f a)
fmap f Nothing = Nothing

-- or

fmap f (Just _) = Nothing
fmap f Nothing = Nothing
```

In contrast, the type `(Int -> Int) -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int` technically tells us very little about what such a function does. In particular, one can forget to use the first argument, which is not too far-fetched a mistake to make IMO:

```
fmap :: (Int -> Int) -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
fmap f (Just a) = Just a
fmap f Nothing = Nothing
```

Comment: On the one hand, I think this is a good answer. It aims to say why the program for a general type may be more limited than the program for a specific type: If one must compute some result for any type then one cannot inspect the values of that type (other than by a few restricted ways). On the other hand, I’m not sure one should be convinced by the answer. It is hard for me to tell this because I know the answer is true. I’m also not sure that this answer would be the right place to explain the point. However I feel like the “technically tells us very little ...” point is a bit wishy-washy.

Answer (score 3):

(I don't like this answer very much, but I'm keeping it, hoping that it can inspire someone to write a better answer.)

---

The standard type classes apply to polymorphic containers, only: containers that can hold any type of values.

For instance, regular functors provide

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

which allows `a` and `b` to be distinct types. This would not be possible to implement for your `Expr`, since it is not polymorphic.

For monomorphic "containers" like your `Expr`, we have the [`mono-traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.9.0) package that provides monomorphic alternatives.

For instance the `MonoFunctor` class can provide

```
omap :: (E -> E) -> C -> C    -- simplified
```

where `E` is the type of the "contained" type and `C` is the type of the container. For your `Expr`, these are the same, and this should work:

```
type instance Element Expr = Expr

instance MonoFunctor Expr where
   omap f expr = ...
```

---

It's hard to decide whether it's better to keep `Expr` monomorphic or turn it into a polymorphic type. It depends on what you are planning to do.

First, monomorphic is simpler. Your recursive type is exactly what you need, no bells and whistles.

Polymorphic is more tricky, and would involve a type-level fixed point:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable  -- not the "other" foldable

-- the functor
data ExprF k 
        = ExprCall { _fname :: Text, _fparams :: [k] }
        | ...
     deriving Functor

-- the fixed point
type Expr = Fix ExprF
```

Downside: now you need to pattern match `Fix` constructors everywhere, e.g.

```
foo :: Expr -> ...
foo (Fix (ExprCall ...)) = ...
```

Major (?) downside: the foldable/traversable instance associated to the functor only care about the *first* layer of your `Expr`, so they are not that useful. E.g. `foldMap` does not really visit the whole expression, since it is defined on `ExprF a` where `a` does not have to be an expression, not on `Expr`. This does not seem very useful.

Upside: you get catamorphism and anamorphisms for free.

Personally, I'd recommend the monomorphic version, unless one feels quite adventurous, and understands `recursion-schemes` quite well.

Comment: Sure I guess that answers the immediate question, but not the meta question of why I should prefer polymorphic always

Comment: @rausted I agree, I'm not really addressing that. After some thinking, I believe the two options "mono/poly-morphic" are not even two comparable options, since they solve different problems. See above the "major downside".

Comment: I see, just curious why did you chose to make `_fparams :: [k]` and not:
`data Expr k = ExprCall { _fname :: k, _fparams :: [Expr k] } ...` which makes more sense imo (making the base type free while keeping the recursive type definition).

Comment: @rausted I see. It depends what you want to affect with your `fmap`: if you want it to affect your `fname`s, then yours is the way to go. If you want the immediate subexpressions, then you need the one in my answer.

Comment: @rausted Actually, I _really_ don't like this answer. It can be quite confusing (reflecting the confusion I have in my mind right now), and I was really tempted to delete it. I won't, only because I hope someone can provide more insight. If that happens, please don't hesitate to move the tick.